# Find right triangle inscribed in circle from two points on separate legs

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

I am getting started on problem solving, and need help with the following exercise of "Solving mathematical problems, a personal perspective". The full question is as follows:

"We are given a circle and two points A and B inside the circle. If possible, construct a right-angled triangle inscribed in the circle such that one leg of the right-angled triangle contains A and the other leg contains B; see figure below. (Hint: solve for the right-angled vertex.)"

[image]

I'm not familiar with these kinds of problems, and quite frankly don't know where to start. If you can provide an answer, could you please start it off with a hint, as I don't really want to be spoon-fed all the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $C$ is the right angle vertex of a triangle that satisfies the problem statement, note that $\triangle ABC$ is also a right triangle with right angle at $C.$

Find the set of all points that can be the right-angled vertex of a right triangle whose other vertices are $A$ and $B.$
The point $C$ cannot be anywhere except in that set of points.

Of course, $C$ must also be on the given circle.

You now have two facts about $C$ which can help you to find that point.
(Note that there might be more than one choice or there might be none, depending on how the construction goes.)

Comment: Just read this, and I want to thank you. I just figured it out (I think). You are supposed to draw a circle such that $AB$ is its diameter, and the solutions are the intersections it has with the original circle. If this is correct, (otherwise please tell me), then maybe you can transform your hint into the full answer for the future.

Comment: You got it from the hint.

Comment: @DollarStoreRichard  What happens if the constructied circle is so small that there is no intersection with the given circle?

Comment: @Mick Then there's no solution. You need two points that subtend a right angle from some point on the circumference of the given circle; it's easy to place two points inside the circle that don't satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @DavidK Right. I just want to let DollarStoreRichard know that his observation is only partially correct.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the circle is of radius $R$ centered at the origin, and that point $A$ is $a$ units away from the center, and makes an angle of $\theta_1$ with the positive $x$ axis.  Similarly, point $B$ is $b$ units from the center, and makes an angle of $\theta_2$ from the positive $x$ axis.

$A = a (\cos \theta_1, \sin \theta_1 )$

$B = b (\cos \theta_2, \sin \theta_2)$

The vertex of the right angle is $V = R (\cos \phi, \sin \phi ) $

Condition is:

$(V - A ) \cdot (V - B ) = 0 $

Expanding,

$ V \cdot V - (A + B) \cdot V + A \cdot B = 0 $

This becomes,

$ R^2 - (A + B) \cdot V + A \cdot B = 0 $

Let $C = A + B$, then the last equation becomes,

$ R C_x \cos \phi + R C_y \sin \phi = R^2 + A \cdot B $

which has two solutions in $\phi$ as long as

$ \left| \dfrac{R^2 + A \cdot B }{R \sqrt{ (A + B) \cdot (A + B ) } } \right| \lt 1 $

Finally we have to find the other two vertices of the right triangle, so let point $A$ lie on $VU$, then

$U = V + t VA$

where we know that U \cdot U = R^2, therefore,

$ (V + t VA) \cdot (V + t VA) = R^2 $

But $V \cdot V = R^2$, and $t $ cannot be zero (this corresponds to $V$ itself), hence,

$ t = - 2 \dfrac{ V \cdot VA }{ VA \cdot VA } $

Finally the point $W$, such that $B$ lies on $VW$ is given by

$W = - U $

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I think this is not in the spirit of the previous problems I've been solving, as they involve more "geometrical" answer.

Comment: What is the prerequisite for the course?  First, can you find a point C that forms a right angle when drawn through A and B, that isn't on the circle?  How do you know if C is on the circle or not?  Will you be using trigonometry or is trig not a prereq of the course?